# Unable to login when custom Devise session controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise token authentication to talk to my mobile app, my session controller has a create method like this:

```
  def create
    logger.info "........#{current_user}"
     warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
     logger.info "authenticate user #{resource_name.inspect}"
     render :status => 200, :json => current_user
  end
```

It work when I login user account A, but if I then try to authenticate account B, the create function always return me account A details, also when inspect current user, it returns account A.

I am wondering how

```
warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
```

works, since it doesn't really look at the params variable, which has the login details?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to login your mobile app users through a token, then you should not modify the standard session behaviour.
Instead, try implementing an `ApiController` (which extends `ApplicationController`) that insert a before filter to login users

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_action :authenticate_user_from_token! # sign_in user using the token

  private
  def authenticate_user_from_token!
    ## Retrieve token in some way, usually from headers ##
    User.find_by_token(token)
    sign_in user, store: false ## this is the magic method from devise
  end
end
```

Of course, I'm considering that you also run standard devise `authenticate_user!` as a before filter in your `ApplicationController`.
All your controller that offers API to your app should than extends this controller, where you can normally use the `current_user` variable.